# jQuery selector children

Tags: jquery, html-table, children

I need to select tbody and insert some tr inside this section:

```
<div id="retour">
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
var table = $('#retour > table > tbody').children();
table.append('<tr>');
table.append( '<td>' + 'MyInfos' + '</td>' );
table.append('</tr>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need

```
var table = $('#retour > table > tbody');
table.append('<tr><td>' + 'MyInfos' + '</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var table = $('#retour tbody');
table.append('<tr><td>' + 'MyInfos' + '</td></tr>');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVkTD/)

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, to get `tbody` use this:

```
var table = $('#retour > table > tbody');
```

To append new cell:

```
table.append('<tr><td>' + 'MyInfos' + '</td></tr>');
```

This:

```
var table = $('#retour > table > tbody').children();
```

Will return you a list of `tr` elements, rather than `tbody`. And it's `tbody` that you want to append new `tr`'s to.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the `.children()`. There are no children in your `tbody` yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var trs = '<tr>';
trs += '<td>' + 'MyInfos' + '</td>';
trs += '<tr>';

$('#retour tbody').html(trs);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use :

```
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addTr(){
                var table = $('#retour > table > tbody');
                table.append('<tr>');
                table.append( '<td>' + 'MyInfos' + '</td>' );
                table.append('</tr>');
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="retour">
        <button onclick="addTr()">Add</button>
        <table>
            <thead>             </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```